# Image src Scraping from Facebook Post using rvest

Tags: r, facebook, facebook-graph-api, rvest

I'm using `rvest` package to scrape a Facebook post and extract the img src url.

```
library(rvest)
UrlPage <- read_html ("https://www.facebook.com/AmazonIN/photos/a.142199085973905.1073741828.100281786832302/458742987652845/?type=3")
UrlPage %>% html_node("#fbPhotoImage")
```

> Error: No matches

`rvest` package works with other websites, but seems to have some issue with Facebook.

Is there any other way to scrape post photos in R?

Comment: Did you try with `Rfacebook` package and Facebook Api?

Comment: Scraping is against Facebook’s ToS. If you want any data from Facebook – **use their API**.

Comment: @Marta Rfacebook doesn't give thumbnail of a post or post photo.

Comment: @CBroe tried to scrape as i couldn't get the photo of a post or the thumbnail generated from Open Graph.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=458742987652845%3Ffields%3Dsource&version=v2.5

Comment: @CBroe using Rfacebook package, I couldn't build any such Graph url. Ultimately i want the img src into R.

Answer (score 0):

First download html page into local System using below code in R

```
download.file(url, destfile.html , quiet = FALSE, mode = "w",
          cacheOK = TRUE,
          extra = getOption("download.file.extra"))
```

and then give local path to read html page, and scrape the image.

Comment: Just returns nothing useful, I'm afraid. Facebook really doesn't want people scraping the site. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648856/scraping-facebook