# Scraping facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping

I need to quickly get the names of about 1000 users that I now only have the facebook id and access tokens of. I'm not comfortable with the FB api yet so I was considering just writing a scraper to retrive the name from the FB page of the user (since I have the id of the users).

1. Is this allowed? I assume it's not "best practice" but how severe is it? Will it get me banned for instance? The data will only be used to complete our user database so no advertisement
2. Alternativly: Can anyone point me in to a good (and up to date) guide of how to get user info using the FB api (keep in mind that I have the ID and the access.tokens of all my users).

Comment: Yes, Facebook may block your IP address if you churn too much.  You should use the Graph API.  Have a look [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, scraping is not allowed and you MUST use the Graph API: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php
2. `/me?fields=name&access_token=[user-access-token]` returns the name of a User - You may run into API limits though, but if it´s a one time thing it should not really matter. If you run into limits, just wait a bit and get the next batch.