# Is there a way to scrape Facebook comments and IDs from a Facebook page like nytimes or the guardian for analytical purposes?

Tags: python, web-scraping, facebook-apps

Is there a way to scrape Facebook comments and IDs from a Facebook page like nytimes or the guardian for analytical purposes !?

Comment: You could possibly use the *requests* module. If the page structure relies heavily on Javascript, you would possibly be better off if you used the *Selenium* module to control your web browser from Python. Then, of course, you could extract the info from the web page as you saw fit.

Answer (score 0):

For scraping, the quick answer is [no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648856/scraping-facebook). Use the [API](https://developers.facebook.com/). I know this question is for Python, but if you use R, there is the Rfacebook package, which has the functions `getPage()` and `getPost()`. A combination of these (i.e. get the page and then loop through the post ids to get the comments with `getPost()` to get comments and the IDs of the commentators) should get you what you want. Apologies, I don't know if there is anything similar for Python.

Answer (score 0):

for using their API, you'll need to "verify" your app to get access to their "pages_read_user_content" or "Page Public Content Access"

at first using the API you might "GET" the page id / page post id / the permalink to the post in the page your own but to scrape the comments with API you'll need to verify a business account.

Comment: I can confirm this.